# How to debug sql files in eclipse?

Tags: sql, eclipse, debugging

I have a big .sql files which contain long queries which are confusing. Is there any possibility to debug in eclipse? if not, is there a good method to see what the single parts of the longer query deliver?

Comment: Can you extract the subqueries and execute them alone? You cannot debug sql queries like e.g. Java code, as it is optimized and executed within the db service. You cannot step through it or watch/inspect any parts during execution.

Comment: P.S.: You can look it up as the difference between imperative (Java, C#, PHP etc.) and declarative (SQL, PROLOG etc.) languages.

Comment: hmmmmmmmmmmm not good

Answer (score 1):

Look for an option to execute the highlighted text, then you can select parts of the query and run them in isolation. As per comment from Uwe, you can't single step the decisions the query engine makes and the rows it sticks together as it builds the result set. you may also need to employ selective commenting out, for example, multiline comment out all the select list and just select *, comment out X number of joined in tables and their related where clauses, and run the query.. keep adding tables back in to the join until things go pear shaped (usually things like duplicate values, or missing rows) and examine the problematic join

Familiarise yourself with the execution plan explanation system; it tells you how the database executed the query, but teaching you how to read it is too broad for a SO answer; some hours work will be needed to gain this understanding

Lastly, make sure your sales are well formatted/indented. There isn't a set standard, so just make up your own style if one isn't already published for your workplace, or get consensus from other debts.. I tend to lay mine to like:

```
Select
  Columns
From
  Table
  Join
  Table
  On
    Predicates
  Join
  (
    Select
      Columns
    ...
  ) subquery
  On
    Predicates
Where
  Predicates
Group/order by
```

Because everything that operates at the same "level" is indented the same amount. Subqueries go in brackets at the same level as the data they produce interacts with other tables.. this makes it vastly easier to see which groups/joins/selects act together and what feeds into what